# ¿Cómo pasar un json a un objeto para realizar las pruebas?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

os comento, me encuentro realizando pruebas unitarias de servidor con jasmine, y no sé como definir un objeto de forma correcta según mi modelo, pues me salen errores de sintaxis. El caso es el siguiente, en mi modelo tengo definido una función juego, dentro de la cual hay un metodo para añadir usuarios. Y otra función usuario. Pongo el código para que se vea más claro.

```
function Juego(){

   this.profesores=[];

   this.agregarProfesor=function(profesor){
     profesor.juego=this;
     this.profesores[profesor._id]=profesor;
   }
   this.registrarProfesor=function(email,clave,callback){
    var ju=this;
    var claveCifrada=cf.encrypt(clave);
    var key=(new Date().valueOf()).toString();

    //var profesor=new Profesor(email,claveCifrada);

    this.dao.encontrarProfesorCriterio({email:email},function(pro){
        if(!pro){
            //profesor.confirmada=false;
            //profesor.key=key;
            //ju.dao.insertarProfesor(profesor,function(usu)....
            ju.dao.insertarProfesor({email:email,clave:claveCifrada,key:key,confirmada:false},function(usu){

                moduloEmail.enviarEmail(email,key,"Haz click aqui para confirmar la cuenta");
                callback({email:'ok'});
            });
        }
        else{
            callback({email:undefined});
        }
    });
   }
   this.loginProfesor=function(email,pass,callback){
    var ju=this;
    var passCifrada=cf.encrypt(pass);
    this.dao.encontrarProfesorCriterio({email:email,clave:passCifrada,confirmada:true},function(pro){
        if (pro){                   
            callback(pro);
            ju.agregarProfesor(new Profesor(pro));
            //ju.agregarProfesor(usr);        
            }
        else{
            callback({email:undefined});
        }
    });
   }
}
function Profesor(usr){
  this._id=usr._id;
  this.juego=undefined;
  this.email=usr.email;
}
```

Tengo un registro de profesor en el que se pasa el email y la clave, y en la base de datos se almacena esto junto al id que le da mlab.

El problema llega a la hora de realizar las pruebas, pues no se como definir el profesor a la hora de crearlo, pues no se puede pasar el JSON con las clave y el email.

```
var modelo = require('./modelo.js');
describe("Pruebas unitarias...", function() {
  var juego;
  var alu1,pro1;
  var sijuega,nojuega;
  var pro={"pepe","clave"};

  beforeEach(function() {
    juego=new modelo.Juego();
    pro1=new modelo.Profesor(pro);

    sijuega=new modelo.SiJuega();
    nojuega=new modelo.NoJuega();
    juego.agregarProfesor(pro1);
   });
}
```

Lo he intentado realizar de esta forma, pero no entiende que es un JSON. Gracias de antemano

Comment: Vale, veo que le pasas el email y la clave al profesor, pero en el modelo tienes un campo llamado "id" y no tienes un campo llamado "clave". ¿Es "id" la "clave"?

Comment: No, el id del profesor, es el que pone automaticamente la base de datos al registrar el usuario. La clave por otro lado, no la tengo en el modelo, la introduzco a través de la interfaz y la cifro en el modelo para guardarla también en la base de datos, pero como se ve, no se la paso al profesor. Si es necesario, pongo el código de registro en base de datos del profesor.

Comment: Pues si, podria ayudarnos ver como registras en la base de datos.

Comment: Vale, lo acabo de añadir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que en ningún momento usas `registrarProfesor` ni `loginProfesor`, pero en `agregarProfesor` estás asignandole una id la cual no tiene porque nunca le has logueado o registrado.

La manera correcta de pasar un JSON como tu quieres seria asi: `var pro={email: "pepe", pass: "clave"};`. Pero me da que tienes que arreglar algunas cositas de como estás haciéndolo, ya que le pasas email y contraseña a la clase y esta no tiene variable de contraseña:

```
function Profesor(usr){
  this._id=usr._id;
  this.juego=undefined;
  this.email=usr.email; // Solo acepta el email.
}
```

Tiene pinta de que te falta que dentro de la clase `Profesor` añadas un metodo de registro/login, pero ahora mismo con lo que nos enseñas no tiene pinta de que vaya a funcionar

Comment: `registrarProfesor`y `loginProfesor` los utilizo en otro archivo del lado del cliente, y si funciona correctamente al realizar el registro y almacenamiento en base de datos, sin embargo llevar razón en la pass, me faltaría o añadir el atributo o no pasarselo en JSON que vaya a crear. Probaré con la segunda a ver el resultado. Gracias

Comment: En efecto, así si funciona, lo he dejado solo con el email. Muchas gracias!!